# How to get single JSON object from SQLITE UNION query?

Tags: json, sqlite, union

I can get UNION result from SQLITE JSON1 extension, but result in two JSON objects, i.e. two "Result" objects.  How to get single JSON object from SQLITE query?

Query:

```
SELECT json_object('Result', 
    json_array(
        json_object('ID',
                    json_group_array(id),
                    'Data',
                    json_group_array(data)
    )
) FROM table1

UNION

SELECT json_object('Result', 
    json_array(
        json_object('timestamp',
                    json_group_array(ts),
                    'name',
                    json_group_array(name)
    )
) FROM table2;
```

What I get:

```
{
  "Result":
  [{
      "id":[1,2,3],
      "data":[10,20,30]
  }]
}
{
  "Result":
  [{
      "timestamp":[1200,1230,1300,1330,1400],
      "name":[Ada,Bella,Candy,Dolly,Ella]
  }]
}
```

What I wish:

```
{
  "Result":
  [{
      "id":[1,2,3],
      "data":[10,20,30],
      "timestamp":[1200,1230,1300,1330,1400],
      "name":[Ada,Bella,Candy,Dolly,Ella]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could achieve this using subqueries:

```
SELECT
    JSON_OBJECT('Result',
        JSON_ARRAY(
            JSON_OBJECT('id',
                        (SELECT JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(id) FROM table1), 
                        'data',
                        (SELECT JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(data) FROM table1),
                        'timestamp',
                        (SELECT JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(ts) FROM table2),
                        'name',
                        (SELECT JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(name) FROM table2)
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: This answered the question.  Only with negative impact for the number of sub-queries will be equal to the json objects to be asked.  If SQL query performance / memory is a constraint, post-processing (e.g. regex) for the result json objects maybe considered.